# How to use templated struct in class c++

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I am trying to use  templated `struct` within a class, but cant figure out how to declare it properly

```
template<typename var>
struct Node
{
    var value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

class Tree
{
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    template<typename var>
    void insert(var key, Node *node);
    template<typename var>
    Node* search(var key, Node *node);
    void deleteTree(Node *node);
    void inOrderTraversePrint(Node* node);
    void preOrderTraversePrint(Node* node);
    void postOrderTraversePrint(Node* node);
    Node* getRoot();
    void resetRoot();
private:

    Node* root;
};
```

I keep getting couple errors " Node is not a type"  and "Invalid use of template-name Node without  an argument list".

I know how to template single `class` and methods within or outside the class, but this is first time I am using `struct` and trying to use templated `struct` within a class.
What is proper way to declare and use `templated struct` within a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Node uses `var` type internally, then it should be templated by it as well:

```
template<typename var>
struct Node
{
    var value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

template<typename T>
class Tree
{
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();

    void insert(T key, Node<T> *node);
    Node<T>* search(T key, Node<T> *node);
    void deleteTree(Node<T> *node);
    void inOrderTraversePrint(Node<T>* node);
    void preOrderTraversePrint(Node<T>* node);
    void postOrderTraversePrint(Node<T>* node);
    Node<T>* getRoot();
    void resetRoot();
private:

    Node<T>* root;
};
```

**Edit**:

> this is first time I am using struct and trying to use templated struct within a class. What is proper way to declare and use templated struct within a class.

You can get away with not templating Tree class, if your tree data always has the same type:

```
class Tree
{
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    void insert(var key, Node<int> *node);
    Node* search(var key, Node<int> *node);
    void deleteTree(Node<int> *node);
    void inOrderTraversePrint(Node<int>* node);
    void preOrderTraversePrint(Node<int>* node);
    void postOrderTraversePrint(Node<int>* node);
    Node<int>* getRoot();
    void resetRoot();
private:

    Node<int>* root;
};
```

**Second Edit**

Variant implementation for nodes:

```
class Node
{
    virtual std::string ToString() = 0; // convert value to string
    virtual ~Node() = default;
    Node *left, *right;
};

template<typename T>
class ValueNode: public Node
{
    T value_;
public:
    ValueNode(T value): Node{ nullptr, nullptr }, value_{ std::move(value) } {}

    std::string ToString() override;
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << value_;
        return oss.str();
    }

    virtual ~ValueNode() = default;
};

class Tree
{
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    template<typename var>
    void insert(var key, Node *node)
    {
        // insert new ValueNode<var>{ key } here
    }

    template<typename var>
    Node* search(var key, Node *node);
    void deleteTree(Node *node);
    void inOrderTraversePrint(Node* node);
    void preOrderTraversePrint(Node* node);
    void postOrderTraversePrint(Node* node);
    Node* getRoot();
    void resetRoot();
private:

    Node* root;
};
```

The idea here is to identify all operations to apply to all node values in the same way (in my example code, that means "conversion of the value to a string") and (first) declare them as abstract operations in `Node`, then implement them depending on the value type (as virtual function implmentations in `ValueNode`).

This will allow you to make abstraction of the fact you have multiple types in the nodes, in the `Tree` class.

That said, if you use boost, you should probably use `boost::variant` or `boost::any` in place of typename var in Node, in your original code.

Comment: Well tree doesnt store any data, node stores int, but I want it to be able to store other data types such as string

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius, I will edit my answer to show that as well.

Comment: Cheers, I actually got it work after your first post with templated class, but  could you explain in more detail what your second edit does, does it allows storing all types as a string?

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius, it allows interpretation of all values as strings. Consider this code: `Node* n = new ValueNode<int>{ 20 };` When you call `n->ToString();` you get a string representation of the node, without caring that the node contains an `int` (if it contained some other type, you would still get a string). This will allow you to treat all `Node` specializations the same, regarding on what type they are specialized on (and make client code easier and uniform).

Comment: Cheers, sounds definitely useful.

Answer (score 2):

> "*`Node` is not a type*" and "*Invalid use of template-name `Node` without an argument list*"

Compiler says you exactly what is wrong. `Node` is indeed not a type. `Node` is a template.

The types are for example `Node<int>`, `Node<std::string>`, `Node<T>` (inside `Tree`) and `Node<var>` (inside `Node`).

Answer (score -1):

Just change the `Node` declarations to `Node<TypeName>`, the compiler is complaining that `Node` is not a type, and it isn't, but `Node<var>` is a class in this case.

Comment: You should provide a code snippet of the solution to illustrate.